# Removing ending vowels from a word

Tags: python, python-3.x

This function receives a string as input and should return the number of syllables in the string.

This function has following conditions:
1. Number of syllables is equal to the number of vowels
2. Two or more consecutive vowels count only as one.
3. One or more vowels at the end of the word are not counted.

This is what I've so far but clearly I'm still missing a lot. I'm not sure how to continue here, so I hope you guys can help.

```
def syllables(word):

    vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u','y']

    # Delete ending vowel of the word since they don't count in number of syllables
    # I've no idea how to remove all ending vowels though
    word = word[:-1]

    # List with vowels that appear in the word
    vowelsList = [x for x in vocals if x in word]

    N = []
    for i in word:
        if i in vowels:
            N += i
    N = len(N)

    return N

print(syllables("bureau"))
# Should print "1" but prints "3" instead
```

Comment: You are removing the last character - not only a vowel - you may still end with a voweld at end that way

Comment: I know that, but I've no clue how to do it. The function should work for all words so word[:-3] is not an option.

Comment: To check the last vowel you can try something like this: 

    if word[-1] in vocals:  
    word=word[:-1]  sorry but I can't figure out how to post code in comments

Comment: we lll .. test the last one, remove if vowel, test again if still vowel remove etc until you happen to have a non-vowel or the word is empty. try `while word and word[-1] in vowel: word = word[:-1]`

Comment: You may also find the [`endswith()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) function to be useful. It can take a tuple as an input (not a list). `word.endswith(tuple(vowels))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you the following simple code:

```
def syllables(word):

    vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y']

    N = 0
    previousLetterIsAVowel = False

    # Perform a loop on each letter of the word
    for i in word.lower():
        if i in vowels:
            # Here it is a vowel
            # Indicate for the next letter that it is preceded by a vowel
            # (Don't count it now as a syllab, because it could belong to a group a vowels ending the word)
            previousLetterIsAVowel = True
        else:
            # Here: it is not a vowel
            if previousLetterIsAVowel:
                # Here it is preceded by a vowel, so it ends a group a vowels, which is considered as a syllab
                N += 1
            # Indicate for the next letter that it is not preceded by a vowel
            previousLetterIsAVowel = False

    return N

print(syllables("bureau"))      # it prints 1
print(syllables("papier"))      # it prints 2
print(syllables("ordinateur"))  # it prints 4
print(syllables("India"))       # it prints 1
```

I also provide a one-line style solution using regex, easily readable too if you know a little bit about regex. It simply counts the number of groups of consecutive vowels that are followed by a consonant:

```
import re

def syllables(word):
    return len(re.findall('[aeiouy]+[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz]', word.lower()))
```

Comment: nice one - should capture capital vowels as well `India` f.e. produces 0 - should be 1?

Comment: You're right, sir ! I have just updated my answer to fix this problem.

Comment: Do you mind explaining the last part after "else:" 
I have a hard time grasping the concept

Besides I don't quite understand how two consecutive vowels only count as one in this function but apparently it works.

Comment: I added comments in my code. I also added a one-line style solution.

Answer (score 0):

To check the last vowel you can try something like this (I wouldn't iterate as you're going to loose whole syllables): -> EX: Italian word "Aia" (threshing floor)

```
if word[-1] in vocals:  
 word=word[:-1]
```

-- sorry but I didn't manage to put 'code' into comments so a posted an answer

Answer (score 0):

I would go for:

```
def syllables(word):
    def isVowel(c):
        return c.lower() in ['a','e','i','o','u','y']

    # Delete ending vowel of the word since they don't count in number of syllables  
    while word and isVowel(word[-1]):
        word = word[:-1]

    lastWasVowel = False
    counter = 0

    for c in word:
        isV = isVowel(c)
        # skip multiple vowels after another
        if lastWasVowel and isV:
            continue
        if isV:
            # found one
            counter += 1
            lastWasVowel = True
        else:
            # reset vowel memory
            lastWasVowel = False


    return counter
```

Stolen from LaurentH:

```
print(syllables("bureau"))      # prints 1
print(syllables("papier"))      # prints 2
print(syllables("ordinateur"))  # prints 4
print(syllables("I"))           # prints 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we have return 1 if there is previousLetterIsAVowel and N returns 0. Example word Bee.

In Addition to Laurent H. answer

```
if N == 0 and previousLetterIsAVowel:
    return 1
else:
    return N
```

Comment: I have read carefully the question, and in the case of "Bee", it should return 0...